# "unrecognized selector sent to instance" on every selector

Tags: iphone, ios, error-handling, unrecognized-selector

i have a huge issue here

I'm developing an app and i was actually very close to have it done. I was testing it many times on many iPhones and after i fired Producy>Analyze it crashes everywhere!

Every `UIButton`, `UIScrollView` etc, everything that i tap, pan or swipe gives me an error of the unrecognized selector.

I tried both cleaning a project, and reboot devices (mac and iphone) but it didn't help. I also recovered recently edited .m file to the last version that worked well but errors still comes.

Does anyone have the idea of what happened and how can i get my project back to life?

I'm really frustrated, please help...

**EDIT**

```
2013-07-03 17:30:24.996 APPNAME[349:907] -[__NSCFData shootAgain:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d1b8e00
2013-07-03 17:30:25.004 APPNAME[349:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData shootAgain:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d1b8e00'
```

Comment: Are the views still linked to the IBOutlets IBActions etc.?

Comment: Could you please paste the whole error message?

Comment: agreed, please post the whole error message

Comment: posted in the edit; @geminiCoder i build my whole layout programmatically, so it can't be it

Comment: The error shows you calling `shootAgain:` on an instance of `NSData`. That's not a standard `NSData` method, is it one you added?

Comment: It looks to me like all your IBOutlets were deallocated, and their memory locations now house other objects. I would check your ownership.